# File.Copy locks source file after completion

Tags: .net, file-locking

We are trying to copy a file from a server, down to a local machine in a .NET 2.0 application (C#), but keep having the source file unnecessarily locked. We suspect it is something configured on the file server that is causing this behaviour, but are not sure what ... can you help?

After the file copy operation, the file server (Windows 2K3 R2) reports that the source file is being held with a read lock, even though no further operation is done with the file on the server. The lock is released once the application quits.

We are able to reproduce the behaviour, even with the most basic code seen below :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sourceFile = @"\\win2K3server\resource\Production\IQE\sourceFolder\iqeconsole.exe";
    string destinationFile = @"d:\destinationFolder\iqeconsole.exe";
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile,destinationFile,true);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The lock occurrs immediately during the `File.Copy()` line executing, and persists after this line has finished. In a more complex application, when the routine with the `File.Copy()` exits(but the application is still running), the lock persists.

Only when the entire application is finished is the lock released.

Changing `sourceFile` to use a mapped drive instead of a UNC path makes no difference to the behaviour.

This behaviour does not happen when the source file is located on another server, or is located locally.

If we add the following line after the `File.Copy`, the lock is released immediately :

```
new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { sourceFile }).Demand();
```

This all sounds to us as though there is something on the server that is causing this behaviour. We have ShadowProtect installed on the server along with McAfee anti-virus. Apart from that, it appears as though there is nothing else installed over-and-above Windows Server and its components.

We are also not sure why Demanding a read permission on the file solves the problem.

If you could answer these questions, we would appreciate it greatly:

1. What is causing the file locks to persist?
2. Why does Demanding a read permission solve the problem?

Comment: UPDATE : this problem is no longer reproducable. It seems to have resolved itself. We couldn't confirm that McAfee was causing the problem either (but this could have to do with the problem resolving while we were investigating).

Comment: @Jarden: I had the same problem with File.Copy. If the next statement after File.Copy() was Delete - it reported access Exception. The problem was occuring nondeterministically, but the above Demand() method solved the problem. As far as I can see this issue is independent from antivirus software.

Comment: I have the same problem but it definately isnt McAfee, Im running AVG, but I have the file montior disabled. I am using Unlocker to tell me what is locking the file and it agrees it is my application. So I guess the jurys still out!! However implementing your solution solves my problems so Im happy for the time being

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably the McAfee on-access scanner that holds the lock. If you only use read access, it is bypassed. I believe that you can use the Sysinternals Process Viewer tool (free from Microsoft) to confirm that.

Not sure what subscription you have for McAfee, but you can define exception rules so that it does not scan this file.

Comment: Hi. Thanks we are investigating this at present.

Comment: For the record, we couldn't confirm that this was the problem using Process Viewer. The problem seems to have mysteriously resolved itself, even though our server guys say they did nothing to the server! Your answer was "best" so have awarded you the points. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, but McAfee is still a good candidate, since I routinely run into this after copying files around. I have kill the McAfee On Access Scanner, then I can delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate this on our file servers.

However, I do know Opportunistic locking is disabled since we're using PeerLock by PeerSoftware.